# Access return value of function in all components

Tags: reactjs

There’s a method in one of my components (Source.jsx) that returns an array. I want to access this array in all my other components (such as Article.jsx which is not necessarily a child component of Source). Is this possible?

```
//Soure.jsx
export default class Source extends React.Component {

  //Returns an array which I want to use in Article.jsx   
getCategories() {
    let sourceCategories = this.fetchAllCategories();
    let sortedCategories = [];
    let index = 0;   
    while(index <= 5){
          sortedCategories.push(sourceCategories[index]);
          index++;
    }  
return sortedCategories; 
  }
}


//Article.jsx
Import Source from '../Source’
let category = Source.getCategories() 
console.log(category) //this is undefined (it says getCategories is not a function)
export default class Article extends React.Component {
  //some methods
}
```

Comment: Your design is wrong if that's how you're attempting to call the function.

Comment: Okay any insights on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think React components are used that way. This line definitely feels wrong.

```
let category = Source.getCategories()
```

The way I understand it you have 2 options.

1. Make the parent component of Source pass a prop function to it, whenever you call getCategories() you should also call that function to pass the value of the array back to the parent, who can then pass it as a prop to its other children. Not sure how nested your components are or how you plan to use this value though, especially since you say you want to access this array in **all** other components so it might be much more trouble than worth.
2. Define a global variable in the style of Window.something, everytime you call getCategories() you assign the resulting array to that global variable. Now you can access it anywhere. Needless to say always be careful with globals and try to avoid using them/ have as little code that mutates them as possible.